# Как правильно посчитать дату

Tags: c#, дата, datetime

У меня есть объект который представляет какую-то рабочую смену, допустим с 20:00 до 7:00:
В ней нет никакой даты и добавить тоже не получится

```
class WorkingShift
{
   public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
   public TimeSpan End { get; set; }
}
```

Я веду статистику по проходам через КПП относительно рабочей смены, так как эта рабочая смена переваливает через сутки, то не получается посчитать полную дату прохода. Для статистики у меня есть объект (ключ на WorkingShift):

```
class StaffPresence
{
   public DateTime EntranceDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime ExitDate { get; set; }

   public DateTime WorkingShiftStart { get; set; }
   public DateTime WorkingShiftEnd { get; set; }
   public Guid WorkingShiftId { get; set; }
}
```

Поля `EntranceDate` и `ExitDate` заполнить просто т.к он берётся с момента прохождения через КПП. А вот как посчитать `WorkingShiftStart` и `WorkingShiftEnd` для следующего кейса: смена началась `01.01.2023 20:00`, заканчивается 02.01.2023 07:00, а вход-выход через КПП был `02.01.2023 01:00` и `02:00`. Как мне посчитать и получить на выходе WorkingShiftStart/WorkingShiftEnd равным `01.01.2023 20:00` и `02.01.2023 07:00`? У меня сейчас есть некоторый алгоритм для вычисления рабочей смены, но он неработает для описанного мною кейса когда смена проходит через разные сутки.

```
public static (DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate) GetWorkingTime(TimeSpan workStart, TimeSpan workEnd, DateTime date)
{
    var start = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
    var end = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);

    if (workStart > workEnd)
    {
        var time = date.TimeOfDay;
        var midnight = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
        if (time >= workStart && time <= workEnd || time >= midnight && time <= workEnd)
        {
            if (time >= workStart && time <= midnight)
            {
                start = start.Add(workStart);
                end = end.AddDays(1)
                    .Add(workEnd);

                return new(start, end);
            }
            else
            {
                start = start
                    .Add(workStart);

                end = end.AddDays(1)
                    .Add(workEnd);

                return new(start, end);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            start = start.Add(workStart);

            end = end.AddDays(1)
                        .Add(workEnd);

            return new(start, end);
        }
    }

    start = start.Add(workStart);
    end = end.Add(workEnd);
    return new(start, end);
}
```

Comment: Может хранить не начало-конец, а начало-длительность?

Comment: @Akina длительность чего? Сейчас я длительность смены могу посчитать через `End - Start` в WorkingShift

Comment: Ага, и имеешь геморрой с переходом даты. А так есть начало 20:00, длительность 11 часов, прибавил, получил 33 часа, и сразу видно, что это 07:00 следующих суток. Поделил на 24:00 и взял остаток, всего делов. А можно и сразу в виде минутного смещения хранить, не 20:00, а 1200.

Comment: причем здесь вход-выход? И как могла смена начаться в 20:00, если вход был в 1:00 следующего дня?

Comment: @Akina Я не уверен как мне это может помочь с тем, чтобы понять в каких сутках находится смена относительно прохода, вход-выход был в час-два ночи, смена началась еще вчера вечером. Как это можно узнать исходя из рассчёта?

Comment: @Эникейщик вход-выход это когда человек приложил карточку к турникету когда выходил/входил на рабочий объект. Рабочая смена - это то, сколько по договору человек работает и в какие часы. Например с 9:00 до 18:00 смена, а человек пришёл на работу к 10 утра, а ушёл в 19 вечера.

Comment: Если с турникета сохраняется только время, без даты - то задача изначально нерешаема.

Comment: Я так и не понял какая связь между входом/выходом и сменой? Что нужно посчитать? Если смену, то при чем тут вход/выход. Если время между вход/выход, то при чем тут смена?

Comment: @Akina с датой, в вопросе написано, что человек например прошёл 02.01 в 01:00 и вышел в 02.01 02:00, но непонятно как мне понять, что он находится именно в смене чьи даты начала и конца 01.01 20:00 и 02.01 07:00.

Comment: Теперь вообще не понял... есть ось времени, на ней есть отрезок смены (01.01 20:00 - 02.01 07:00) и отрезок выхода (02.01 01:00 - 02.01 02:00). Что, проблема определить, что один внутри второго?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это несложная задача.

1. Во-первых, нужно использовать реальные моменты времени для начала смен, то есть не 20:00 и 07:00, а "02.01.ХХХХ 20:00" смена № 1,"03.01.ХХХХ 07:00" смена № 2, "03.01.ХХХХ 20:00" смена № 3 и т. д.
2. Примем, что смена человека определяется большей продолжительностью его пребывания в течение 1-го посещения предприятия, то есть если работник зашёл в 19:00, а вышел в 23:00, то 3 часа будут относится к смене с 20:00.
3. Разбиваем пребывание работника на части, максимум 3, то есть добросовестный работник может придти до начала смены, а уйти после её окончания. Из этих кусков (от 1 до 3) выбираем наибольший и смотрим, в какую смену он попал.

Как определить попадание в смену? Для момента времени AMoment:

1. Если AMoment < 'AMoment.Day 07:00' - смена с '(AMoment.Day - 1) 20:00' до 'AMoment.Day 07:00'.
2. Если AMoment >= 'AMoment.Day 20:00' - смена с 'AMoment.Day 20:00' до '(AMoment.Day + 1) 07:00'.
3. Иначе это смена с 'AMoment.Day 07:00' до 'AMoment.Day 20:00'.

Примерно так.